# Is there a Null OutputStream in Java?

Tags: java, outputstream

I need to specify an `OutputStream` for an API I'm using, but I don't actually have a need for the output.  Does Java have an `OutputStream` equivalent to `> /dev/null`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since Java 11, there is a static utility that does exactly what you need, a static factory method [`OutputStream.nullOutputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#nullOutputStream()):

> Returns a new OutputStream which discards all bytes. The returned stream is initially open. The stream is closed by calling the close() method. Subsequent calls to close() have no effect.

Answer (score 128):

Java 11+:

[OutputStream.nullOutputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#nullOutputStream())

Java 11-:

```
/** Writes to nowhere. */
public class NullOutputStream extends OutputStream {
  @Override
  public void write(int b) throws IOException {}
}
```

Comment: This can also be easily implemented wherever you need it using something like this:

`OutputStream nullOutputStream = new OutputStream()
    {
        @Override
        public void write(int b)
        {
        }
    };`

Comment: for performance reasons you should also override the other wirte(...) methods, see comments in the java.io.OutputStream source code

Answer (score 71):

Apache Commons IO has the following:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullOutputStream.html

Answer (score 46):

It's not mentioned yet, so I'll also add **[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [ByteStreams](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html).[nullOutputStream()](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#nullOutputStream())**, as some might prefer Guava over Apache Commons IO or already have it in their project.

**Note:** If you use an older version of Guava (from 1.0 to 13.0), you want to use [com.google.io.NullOutputStream](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/5e074af6a526af39a4410a836517e57c72aa50bb/javadoc/com/google/common/io/NullOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 15):

Rehashing the answers already provided -

Java does not have a `NullOutputStream` class. You could however roll your own `OutputStream` that ignores any data written to it -  in other words `write(int b)`, `write(byte[] b)` and `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` will have empty method bodies. This is what the Common IO `NullOutputStream` class does.

Comment: here http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/commons-io-2.0/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullOutputStream.java.shtml

Answer (score 5):

Java 11 added [OutputStream.nullOutputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#nullOutputStream())

Answer (score 3):

No, but it is pretty easy to implement.

See this question ["How to remove System.out.println from codebase"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572134/how-to-remove-system-out-printlns-from-codebase/572222#572222)

And then you just have to:

```
System.setOut( DevNull.out );
```

<strike>Or something like that :)</strike>

[System.setOut(PrintStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29)

Comment: I get the error:  "cannot assign a value to final variable out"

Answer (score 2):

There is new boy in the town, that takes care of this like a charm, just few lines of code should work.
Its **[JDK 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/)** and [nullWriter()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Writer.html#nullWriter()) has been introduced there, that takes care of this. Here goes the code to deal with same old problem, new way without worrying about Operating System(OS).

```
String fileContent = "Welcome to StackOverflow readers !! Here goes the question link...";
Writer writer = Writer.nullWriter();
writer.write(fileContent);
writer.close();
```

Hope this may help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you're looking for, I was looking for the same thing:
This is for redirecting output streams from standard error, standard out in ProcessBuilder objects.

> Blockquote

```
pb.redirectError( ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo( new File( "NUL:" ) ) );
```

- Dom

Comment: This is Windows specific.