# Java: Block method from using standard output

Tags: java, output

I am using a proprietary API in Java. Its `connect` method unleashes a barrage of log messages on my standard output. That makes it impossible for me to read the messages from my own logger. Unfortunately, the `setOut` method of the API does not work.

Is there a way to block the `connect` method from writing to standard output?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question but you could set "System.out" to a dummy output file before calling the connect method.

Comment: If it uses `System.out`, then `System.setOut` should work. If it uses some other means (e.g. JNI and writing to stdout) then it's complicated. In C, you would do something like that: `oldout = dup(stdout); close(stdout); open("/dev/null"); ...; close(stdout); dup(oldout); close(oldout);`

Comment: Find out what logger the API is using and lower its log level. Complain to the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.setOut(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));` (you may or may not want to save the reference to the ByteArrayOutputStream) before calling the appropriate method, since you can't modify the method itself, and `System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));` after calling it

Comment: I created a [Null OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691813/is-there-a-null-outputstream-in-java) and set `System.setOut(new PrintStream(new NullOutputStream()));`. That blocks everything I send via `System.out.println("...");` but not the API output (nor my logger's output, strangely).