# how to delete all system.out.println statements of the project automatically including all multiline Sop statements

Tags: java, eclipse

Actually I want to automate the process of removing all the `System.out.println()` statements from the entire project before delivering the project to the client. How to do it?

Comment: Which `IDE` you are using ?

Comment: I dont want to replace them with any statement, i just want to delete all the occurences of System.out.println() statement of the project automatically.

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044205/system-out-println-removal-comment-from-multiple-java-source-files)

Comment: Do you really want to *delete* them? Or do you just want to disable "debugging" output to stdout? And do you want to do this once and for all or just leave it there and do it just before release?

Comment: Not that you asked for a more convenient way, but had you used a logging framework in the first place, you could just have disabled the code. Just an idea for upcoming projects.

Comment: if you will be further developing the application after handing a first release to the client (and usually otherwise too), using `System.out.println()` is a bad idea anyways. Use a configurable logging framework, e.g. logback, saves you from that work. C and the likes have a preprocessor which can strip out debugging code altogether.

Comment: You should consider using log frameworks

Comment: This question has already been asked before

Comment: Yes i really want to delete them all automatically. @proskor

Comment: Log4j and other customized Logging frameworks are there in place, but still developers have used Sop's. Cant help. Now i have got to remove all the Sop's from the entire project.

Answer (score 2):

Press ctrl+H go to File search. Fill containing text as `System.out.println(*);` , File name pattern as `*.*` and click on Replace Button.

After the search it prompt for a replacing text, Press **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Replace functionality of any decent text editor like Notepad++. Just replace the regular expression `System.out.println(\*)` with an empty string

Comment: And what will happen to `System.out.println(SOME_STRING);`? (Hint: Some regex is probably needed)

Comment: @amit With Notepad++ you can use regular expressions to do a replacement.

System.out.println(\*);

Comment: Well, it should have been said. Also what happens for `System.\nout.\nprintln(SOME_STRING);` (But the editted answer is getting better)

Comment: Oscar, is that a valid regex? I don't know their flavor in Notepad++, but no javascript/Java/Perl regex looks like that...

Comment: @tucuxi No, it isn't, I just wrote it as a sample.

Comment: This is not so simple. Some time SOME_STRING will extends to multiple lines. Ex System.Out...("fdf" +"fddfdfdfd" + ....

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Regex can handle matches in multiples lines too, so same solution still is valid.

Answer (score 0):

use the "find all" function of your IDE
and delete it manually

with Eclipse:

CTRL+H

then "File search"

type "System.out.println(*);" and click "Replace..."

Answer (score 0):

Click CTRL+F and choose Replace. Then, replace System.out.println with //System.out.println

Comment: And what will happen to `System.out.println(SOME_STRING);`? (Hint: Some regex is needed)

Comment: If you write System.out.println, without the brackets, that will take care of everything. (I edited my answer)

Comment: But then the code won't compile, you will have to manually delete the `(STRING)` from everywhere.

Comment: Well then, probably System.out.println(*), I haven't used regular expressions for finding and replacing, but it might work.

Comment: Replace system.out.print with //system.out.print (would be a problem with multiline) or just replace it with something like log4j

Comment: Or, an even easier fix that will work for sure, is to replace it with //System.out.println

Comment: @user3722371 No, it won't. A long diagnostic message might be split across lines of source code, leaving you with invalid trailing lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `find in Project` option then give `System.out.println(` to your search criteria then remove them all. and match criteria will not be match whole word.

If INtellij Idea then `Edit -> Find ->Find in Path`.

If NetBeans then `Edit -> Find In Projects`

Comment: Have you read any comment for other answer? What will happen if you have System.out.println(SOME_THING)?

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan : Yes I have edited the answer and Sorry for that.

Comment: Now what, code won't compile

Comment: Now what mean, it will find the `System.out.println(` then we have to delete that line. `Intellij Idea` is great for that.

Answer (score 0):

If You are want to automate this kind of stuff, you can use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and preprocess your source code files with [ReplaceRegExp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task. We use this to compile the product version into the binaries.

This is taken (and modified slightly) from the online doc:

```
<replaceregexp match="System.out.println(.*);" replace="" flags="g" byline="true">
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [plugin](http://eclipseo.blogspot.com/2013/05/updatesite-available-for-eclipse-utils.html) which does exactly what you want. This will Comment / Remove out all `System.Out`'s. Check [this](http://www.ancitconsulting.com/tiki-index.php?page=eclipse-util%20toolkits&pagenum=3) link also. Its is said [here](http://eclipseo.blogspot.in/2013/05/commenting-systemoutprintln-from.html) that it is a solution for [System.out.println removal/comment from multiple java source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044205/system-out-println-removal-comment-from-multiple-java-source-files) post.