# In Eclipse use find/replace to comment multiline statements

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

While debugging code, I added a bunch of lines in the form of

```
System.out.println("DEBUG: (Some statement)");
System.out.println("DEBUG: (Some statement)" + (Some expression));
System.out.println("DEBUG: (Some statement)" + (Some expression) + "Some other text");
System.out.println("DEBUG: (Some statement)" 
    + (Some expression)
    + "(Some other statement)");
System.out
    .println("DEBUG: (Some statement)" 
        + (Some expression)
        + "(Some other statement)");
```

where `(Some expression)` and `(some statement)` are expressions and statements respectively.

Now that I'm done debugging the code, I would like to be able to comment it out using find and replace, and to uncomment it later, if more bugs appear.

I have a regex that works for the single-line statements.
    (System.out.println("DEBUG:[^,]+"\n)

Is there a regex that works for the multiline statements?

Comment: Can't you simply select all those lines and press `Ctrl + Shift + /`?

Comment: @KrishPrabakar What does Ctrl+Shift+/ do?

Comment: It surrounds your statements with a [multi line comment](http://javadude.com/articles/comments.html) (/* */)

Comment: @Krish Ah. The problem is that there are many lines that need to be commented and uncommented later. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: To uncomment those lines, you can use `Ctrl + Shift + \ (backslash)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest go for this solution. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24160549/1391924).

Any way regular expression as you asked:

**Commenting**

Find string: `(?m)(?s)(System[\W.]*?out[\W.]*print[\w]*\(\"DEBUG:(.*?);)`

Replace string: `/*\1*/`

**Un commenting**

Find string:

`(?m)(?s)/\*((?m)(?s)(System[\W.]*?out[\W.]*print[\w]*\(\"DEBUG:(.*?);))\*/`

Replace string: `\1`

Refer [meta character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it when I get back to my laptop.

Comment: One issue with the regex is that I've been using single line comments, though that's a minor issue and easy to fix.

Another issue is that the first regex also matches System.in, System.err.println and anything that starts with System., which is an issue because I have a good amount of those. 

I'd upvote, but I don't have the rep :(.

Comment: @alphadelta Now I changed the regular expression. Test it if it works then accept and upvote my answer

Comment: Works perfectly. Sorry for the late response; I've been busy for the past couple days.